# Can not install Workflow Manager to work with SharePoint Server 2013 farm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation-4, sharepoint-workflow

I installed SP Server 2013 and Workflow Manager in one server. When I configure Workflow Manager to work with SharePoint Server 2013 farm (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588), I am encountering this error:
[image]

Help me plz

Comment: You have extra slash before port number. Must be http://101ducna4:12291. Are you execute powershell as administrator?

Comment: I'm try http://101ducna4:12291, but get the same error. Yes, i run command by System admin

Answer (score 0):

hi your input url is wrong

it should be `http://101ducna4:12291` instead `http://101ducna4/:12291`

Comment: I'm try by your command code but get the same error. it can not find SPSite url

Answer (score 0):

Probably a loopback check issue.

Does the url work in Internet Explorer?
Make sure to disable loopbackcheck. Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861.